# [SQL]Find the location, pallet, case, part numbers, and total unit quantity by part number

Tags: sql

Facing error while executing a query for :

Find the location, pallet, case, part numbers, and total unit quantity by part number

```
[select l.stoloc,
    il.lodnum,
    ins.subnum,
    p.prtnum,
    sum(i.untqty)
  from invdtl as i
 inner
 join invsub as ins
 on i.subnum = ins.subnum
inner
 join invlod as il
 on il.lodnum = ins.lodnum
inner
 join locmst as l
 on l.stoloc = il.stoloc
 and l.wh_id = il.wh_id
inner
join prtmst as p
 on p.prtnum = i.prtnum
where l.stoloc = '10A10B'
group by p.prtnum] catch(-1403)
```

This is written in MOCA language if you don't know about MOCA kindly ignore catch and square brackets and please help me out to find the correct query.

Currently I am getting following error while executing the above query:

[image: error]

Comment: `add in group by l.stoloc and p.prtnum.`

Comment: Getting syntax while after writting group by l.stoloc and p.prtnum ... Error says: incorrect syntax cear the keyword 'and'

Comment: In your query you are aggrigating `SUM()` of one column other columns will have multiple values either you have to include it in your group by clause or apply aggrigate functions on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query you are aggregating `SUM()` of `i.untqty` other columns will have multiple values either you have to include it in your `group by` clause or apply aggregate functions on them. Depending on the your requirements.

```
select l.stoloc,
    il.lodnum,
    ins.subnum,
    p.prtnum,
    sum(i.untqty)
  from invdtl as i
 inner
 join invsub as ins
 on i.subnum = ins.subnum
inner
 join invlod as il
 on il.lodnum = ins.lodnum
inner
 join locmst as l
 on l.stoloc = il.stoloc
 and l.wh_id = il.wh_id
inner
join prtmst as p
 on p.prtnum = i.prtnum
where l.stoloc = '10A10B'
group by p.prtnum,l.stoloc,il.lodnum,ins.subnum
```

I am currently applying the `Group By` but you need to apply your related aggregate functions or `Group by` clause.

Comment: What u mean by related aggregate functions, I need to sum only untqty. For rest of the columns, can I use group by clause only?

Comment: So you are applying the Aggregate function `SUM`, when  you apply the aggregate function you tell the query executioner that you want to sum the multiple row values into single row. But you are selecting the other rows with it like `p.prtnum,l.stoloc,il.lodnum,ins.subnum` but you did not mention what to do with there multiple values. So for to tell the query executioner you need to either apply the aggregate functions on them or include it in the group by.

Comment: If your requirements are that then yes. But you  need to read more about group by and aggregate functions as that would give you the more understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 1):

`select l.stoloc,il.lodnum,ins.subnum,p.prtnum,sum(i.untqty) from invdtl as i  inner  join invsub as ins  on i.subnum = ins.subnum inner  join invlod as il  on il.lodnum = ins.lodnum inner  join locmst as l  on l.stoloc = il.stoloc  and l.wh_id = il.wh_id inner join prtmst as p on p.prtnum = i.prtnum where l.stoloc = '10A10B' group by l.stoloc,il.lodnum,ins.subnum,p.prtnum;`

this should work I think as you are missing `l.stoloc` in group by clause.because its thumb rule for `sql` query to include all `select` stuffs in `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks, Coder of code already solved the query before you so can't mark your answer as correct, sorry!

Comment: @SiddharthSachdeva atleast you can give me an upvote if it was worth to you

Comment: I have given the up vote, will be appreciated if u do the same